# MySQL - One to many query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, one-to-many

I have one table like this:

```
[Exam]
[exam_id] [exam_name]
   1        Test1
   2        Test2
```

And other table like this:

```
[Module]
[module_id] [module_name] [exam_id]
    1          Module1      1
    2          Module2      1
    3          Module1      2
```

Clearly, we see how Test1 has 2 modules assigned and Test2 has on module assigned

I want get a query joining both tables where the output be something like this:

```
Test 1    Module1
          Module2

Test 2    Module1
```

I did the following:

```
SELECT `exam`.'exam_id', 'exam_name', 'module_name'
FROM (`exam`) JOIN `module` ON `exam`.`exam_id`=`module`.`exam_id`
```

But I got an output with duplicates exam names:

```
Test 1 Module 1
Test 1 Module 1

Test 2 Module1
```

I want to remove the extra Test 1 since these is being showed on a view which I'm using a foreach

Can you guys help me with this? .. I'm using codeIgniter so you can provide me the query in codeigniter too.

Thank you

Comment: Yea ... not going to happen, sorry. Thats not how SQL works. You ***could*** put together some crazy UNION that blotted out the exam name for anything but a 'header row', but honestly, these kind of reporting/display tasks are better handled post-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will return the exam_name in every row. To prevent it from showing in your view, you need to set up some extra logic PHP side to do just that. eg

```
$exam = null;

foreach($rows as $row){

    if($row['exam'] !== $exam){
        echo '<h1>'. $row['exam'] .'</h1>';
        $exam = $row['exam'];
    }

    echo '<p>'. $row['module'] .'</p>';

}
```

This only prints the exam if it's different from the previous row.